# Jsoup runs incorrectly on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsoup

I try to login facebook with JSoup, when test with console app or Tomcat server webapp, it runs well:

```
String userAgent = BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38.getUserAgent();
Connection conn1 = Jsoup.connect("https://m.facebook.com");
Document document = conn1.userAgent(userAgent).execute().parse();
Element form = document.select("form").get(0);
Elements inputs = form.select("input");
Connection conn2 = Jsoup.connect(form.absUrl("action")).userAgent(userAgent);
for (Element input: inputs) {
    conn2.data(input.attr("name"), input.val());
}
conn2.data("email", "mail@gmail.com").data("pass", "mypass");
Connection.Response response1 = conn2.method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
System.out.println(response1.url());
Document doc1 = response1.parse();
Elements h3 = doc1.select("h3");
for (Element element: h3) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

> response1.url() is https://m.facebook.com/home.php?_rdr

But when I try with Google App Engine app, it cannot login but shows the page with message "you have to login first" (I guess that the request try to access some other url)

> response1.url() is https://m.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fhome.php%3Frefsrc%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fm.facebook.com%252F%26refid%3D8&refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&refid=8&_rdr

I change the password to make it incorrect, it shows the incorrect-password page. So I think with correct password, the request goes to the proper page. But why with correct password, it redirects to other page?
I don't think there is any different thing between console app and GAE that makes the request different!

Comment: I would ask what you are trying to do. It looks like you are trying to connect to Facebook and login. However, have you tried just doing a re-connect to the home after trying to log in?

Comment: @Gann14 yes, I tried, and still not login

Answer (score 1):

App Engine can do a few strange things from time to time when you're creating outbound HTTP requests from the server.  Depending on how JSoup implements the underlying request, it's possible something is getting mixed up. Under the hood, it would likely need to use [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests).

One thing you could try here is to use [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/).  Outbound requests aren't going to be piped through UrlFetch or the Sockets API there, since ultimately your app is just running on Google Compute Engine.

If your app isn't using a ton of the App Engine APIs, this could be an easy way to get around the issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to use GAE Flex because it requires payment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that after successful login, facebook returns some *redirect* (several sequential redirects?) as a response.

When you run your app outside GAE, java just follows those redirects automatically, and eventually returns `https://m.facebook.com/home.php?_rdr` as a result.

On the other hand, when running inside GAE, GAE's URLFetch library [follows up to 5 redirects only](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests#responses) (or none, if configured so).

If that's the case, then you could follow those redirects in your code.

Can you also print `response1.statusCode()` to check this hypothesis?